# How to have an Ionic >=2 scrollable ion-list under fixed search bar

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, flexbox

I have an Ionic >=2 application where I would like to have 2 or 3 fixed rows at the top of the page, and then have the rest of the page as a scrollable list (and later I want it to be virtual, but just want to get the simple list working forst).

As a simplified example, I have the following [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/z0DzVL?p=preview). The markup repeated here is..

```
    <ion-header>
          <ion-navbar>
            <ion-title>{{ appName }}</ion-title>
           </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content scroll=false>
       <ion-grid>
         <!-- Row 1 fixed at top -->
         <ion-row>
           <ion-col>
             <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>   
           </ion-col>
           <!-- Other cols -->
         </ion-row>

        <!-- Row 2 Scrollable list -->
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-list>    
              <ion-item *ngFor="let item of data">      
                <div>{{item}}</div>
              </ion-item>          
            </ion-list >  
          </ion-col>
       </ion-row>

       </ion-grid>
    </ion-content>
```

The problem is the search bar also scrolls with the list, whereas I would like this to always remain visible at the top of the page.

Does anyone know why I have the search bar also scrolling when this is in a completely separate row to the ion-list? Should I be using an ion-grid in this way?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: your plunkr doesnt seem to have your code..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`ion-content`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/content/Content/) does not have `scroll` input property to disable it.
If you need to have `searchbar` always visible, I suggest you place it in a toolbar.

```
<ion-header>
      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>{{ appName }}</ion-title>
       </ion-navbar>
       <ion-toolbar>
           <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
       </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Or use [`ion-scroll`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/scroll/Scroll/) with a fixed height.

```
<ion-grid>
    <!-- Row 2 Scrollable list -->
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
          <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-scroll style="width:100%;height:100vh" scrollY="true">
           <ion-list scroll="true">
          <ion-item *ngFor="let item of data">
            <div>{{item}}</div>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        </ion-scroll>

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-grid>
```

[**Sample Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0zaHLSxK16fZ1IssBGYf?p=preview)

Update: To answer @JohnDoe's comment.. in order to get scroll list to take the height of rest of the screen use [Viewport percentage height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) to set the height of `ion-scroll`.

Comment: great thanks. I had my scrolls totally mixed up (yet again). I forget the list does not have it's own internal scroll, so we need the ion-scroll.

Comment: great solution. but one thing, how can we set the scroll list to take the height of rest of the screen. As per your demo, it takes only 100px. Most of the devices have different screen resolutions. It would be nice if the list gets height to fill the empty screen space available now. @suraj

Comment: @JohnDoe you can get [viewport percentage height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths). set `height:100vh`

Comment: Using 100vh does not work, even in the plunker link above. The list expands beyond the the viewport height and the whole page scrolls.

Comment: @JohnVolkya I suppose `100vh` takes a bit more as the space for the searchbar needs to be included.Try maybe `80vh` or `70vh`

Comment: It would be better if we did not have to guess or calculate this height.

Comment: It is not working, giving me an error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'ion-scroll' is not a known element:"

Comment: @Kamlesh depends on what version of ionc are you using? and whether you have imported ionic-module if you are indeed using ionic v2

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to have a list at the bottom of the page scroll without scrolling the whole page:

HTML

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table-row">
            <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row last-row">
            <div class="table-cell cell-content-outer-wrapper">
                <div class="cell-content-inner-wrapper">
                    <div class="cell-content">
                        <ion-list>
                            <ion-item *ngFor="let item of data">
                                <div>{{item}}</div>
                            </ion-item>
                        </ion-list>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.table-row {
   display: table-row;
}
.table-cell {
   display: table-cell;
}
.last-row {
   height: 100%;
}
.cell-content-outer-wrapper {
   height: 100%;
}
.cell-content-inner-wrapper {
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
   overflow: auto;
}
.cell-content {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

Makes use of lots of divs but it worked for me in ionic 2 and in onsen-ui as well when I was facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ionic 5 with Vue. I wanted to have a fixed content at the top of the page with a scrollable list below. This is all I had to do:

```
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header :translucent="true">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-back-button defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Page title</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-content>
        <!-- Here is the fixed content -->
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

    <ion-content>
      <!-- This content will scroll -->
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Pokémon Yellow</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Mega Man X</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>The Legend of Zelda</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Pac-Man</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Super Mario World</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
```

The trick was in putting the fixed content between `<ion-header>` and `<ion-content>` components.

Answer (score -1):

I've made an npm packge that create this fixed scroll.

You need to install and use the npm package on your project (ionic3)

```
npm install --save ionic2-fixedscroll-directive
```

Import the ngFixedScrollDirective module on your page or AppModule

```
import { NgFixedScrollModule  } from 'ionic2-fixedscroll-directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(MyPage),
    NgFixedScrollModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyPage
  ]
})
export class MyPageModule {}
```

Create the SASS CSS to fix the element

```
your-page {
   ion-searchbar {
       &.fixed {
        @extend .toolbar; //optional
        position: fixed;
        top: 0; 

        transition: all 0.5s ease;

        &.searchbar-ios {
            transform: translateY(calc(#{$navbar-ios-height} + #{$cordova-ios-statusbar-padding}));
        }

        &.searchbar-md {
            transform: translateY(#{$navbar-md-height});
        }

        &.searchbar-wp {
            transform: translateY(#{$navbar-md-height});
        }
        z-index: 3; //zindex to put it on top of some ionic components
    }
   }
}
```

And add the directive to the component or element that you need to fix on top of the page (outside the toolbar)

```
<YourComponent fixed-scroll></YourComponent>
```

More info on the directive git repo: https://github.com/joao-gsneto/ionic2-fixedscroll-directive